# How to make an HTML login page that connects to a database

Tags: html, authentication

Let’s say I have a *login.html* page with an HTML template.

And I want to use that *login.html* template to log in to another *login.php* page.

Say, when a user types in an email address and password in *login.html*, I want that *login.html* page to type the same email and password in my another website which has a *login.php* page.

For this example, let’s take blesta. It has a *login.php* page, but the landing page is simple and is not beautiful.

I have another HTML page named *login.html* which looks sleek and beautiful, but I don't want to transfer users to blesta *login.php* and then they enter their credentials, but rather I want them to enter those credentials in the *login.html* page and those credentials be automatically typed/used in blesta's *login.php* page and then they get redirected/transferred to *dashboard.php* inside blesta.

Is it possible?

I tried too much searching, but I couldn't find any answer yet.

Answer (score -1):

HTML is a *[markup language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language)*, not a programming language, so it can't connect directly to any database.

But you can send the form's action of your *login.html* to the same of the *login.php* of blesta and add the same name of each input.

Comment: Yes that is what I wanted to know and how am I supposed to do that? When a user type his username and password on the html login tab how can it send the details to blesta's login.php and then login.

Comment: Use the Google DevTools and inspect the form of blesta's login, and copy the direction of the attribute **action="..."** and add it to your form. _Remind to use the same name of each input_ .